# problema con ajax y php: error php undefined index pais

Tags: php, ajax

Describo mi problema: el objetivo es integrar el uso de ajax con código php. Tengo un php llamado país en el que hay un formulario desplegable y seguirá las siguientes instrucciones al seleccionar un valor llamará a la función ajax, la función ajax llamará a otro php:

El otro php leerá de la base de datos paises de la tabla provincias que contenga las provincias del pais seleccionado y se nos mostrará un desplegable con dichas provincias.

Mi error es el siguiente: Notice: undefined index pais in leerbd.php en la línea 26 ($query = "SELECT * FROM provincias where pais =  '".$_GET['pais']."'";)`

pais.php:

```
<?php




include 'leerbd.php';


?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>

    <form action="" method="post" align="center">
            Pais: <select name="pais" id="pais" onchange="Provincias()"> <!-- en el onchange le ponemos el nombre de la funcion-->
            <option value="">[Seleccione el pais]</option> 
            <option value="es">España</option>
            <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
        </select><br />
        <div id="provincias"></div>  
    </form>





    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*función para crear el objeto de AJAX que permite la conexión*/

        function getHTTPObject(){
            if (window.ActiveXObject)
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            else {
                alert("No soportado"); 
                return null;
            }

        }



        function Provincias(){
            var pais = document.getElementById('pais').value; //recogemos el pais
            httpObject = getHTTPObject(); 
            if (httpObject != null) {
                httpObject.open("GET", "leerbd.php?pais=" + pais ,true); 
                httpObject.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(httpObject.readyState == 4  && httpObject.status == 200) 
                    /*cuando acabe de cargar leerbd.php /*mostramos el contenido generado en suma.php */
                    {

                         document.getElementById('provincias').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
                    }
                }
                httpObject.send(null);
            }
        } 



    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

leerbd.php:

```
<?php

//Conectando y seleccionando la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('No pudo conectarse: ' .mysqli_error());


echo 'Conexion correcta </br>';



mysqli_select_db($conexion, 'paises') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
    echo 'Provincia : <select id="provincia" name="provincia">';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM provincias where pais =  '".$_GET['pais']."'";

    //echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' .mysqli_error());
    if($result){
        echo 'llego </br>';
        //si tenemos registros
        $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($row_cnt !== 0) {
            echo 'llego 2';
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['provincia'].'</option>';
            }   
        } else {
            echo 'No se han encontrado registros';
        }
    }


    echo '</select>';
    mysqli_close($conexion);


?>
```

`

Comment: Creo que en el leerbd.php, en vez de $_GET['pais'] debería ser un $_POST['pais'], ya que en esa página estás posteando ese valor no?
Ahora no tengo el ordenador delante para hacer el código pero creo que puede ser eso

Comment: Eso no es así, la petición ajax tiene especificada que la comunicación es GET y los parámetros que le pasa son mediante la url, lo cual es GET indiscutiblemente, no obstante sí que sería una buena práctica cambiar la comunicación de GET a POST.

Comment: PD: También es siempre una buena práctica (ya que tienes en el `select` una opción con valor vacío) comprobar antes de realizar la petición ajax si el valor del input tiene longitud mayor a 0, vamos : `if (pais.length > 0){[...]}`.

Comment: has probado a hacer un `console.log(pais)` en js para comprobar captas el país como debes?

Comment: no comprendo por qué haces un `include leerbd.php`

Comment: No haces uso de nada del php en pais.php, solo para incluir el archivo, pero si haces una petición ajax para recoger los datos no necesitas importar nada, de hecho puede que eso te cause todo el problema

Comment: si, leerbd.php y pais.php están en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Dani revisando más de cerca el código constato que estabas enviando `null` al servidor. Revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: @DaniSerra pero me refiero que no necesitas incluirlo solo para hacerle una petición ajax y no lo usas para otra cosa.. con lo cual.. el include es innecesario, si miras mi respuesta podrás ver que incluso puede ser la causa del problema

Comment: @DaniSerra ¿cuál es el error que te da en la query? Tu código PHP en `leerbd.php` necesita varias  mejoras. Puedes depurar si la información está llegando bien mediante `print_r($_GET);`. Si recoge bien los datos enviados desde Ajax entonces te puedo sugerir un mejor código en dicho archivo.

Comment: El error tal cual es: Notice:  Undefined index: pais in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\leerbd.php en la línea donde está .$_GET['pais'].
Es decir tanto en la query como haciendo el print_r($_GET['pais']);
Por lo que no llega a pasar la variable de pais.html a leerbd.php

Comment: Prueba a hacerlo mediante `POST` como he puesto en la respuesta editada. Fíjate que los datos se pasarían en el método `send`. Y para depurar en PHP haz un `print_r($_POST);`, así, **tal cual**, sólo para verificar si está enviando cualquier cosa, pues de ese modo te mostrará **todo lo que haya en el POST**.

Comment: Modificando la función de provincias en pais.html y poniendo un print_r($_POST); en leerbd.php me muestra en pais.html Array ( [pais] => es ). Por lo que si que llega a leerbd.php. Mi duda ahora es la siguiente como le paso a la variable $query el dato pais. No lo puedo hacer directamente con el post pues me da error de array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es el siguiente:

```
<?php




include 'leerbd.php';


?>
```

Ya que eso va a cargar el archivo php en tu página al cargar esta. Para hacer la petición ajax no necesitas importar el archivo, solo tienes que especificar bien cual será la ruta a la que quieres llamar, al hacer el `include`, dentro del `leerbd.php` estás esperando un parámetro `$_GET['pais']`, el cual al principio no existe, eso siempre te va a petar.
Espero que te haya servido :)

Comment: PD: puedes cambiar el `pais.php` por un `pais.html` sin ningún tipo de problema. El `include 'leerbd.php';` eliminalo directamente.

Comment: el include está al principio de pais.php

Comment: @A.Cedano metete en la edición, y podrás ver el código completo, yo tengo una edición propuesta arreglandolo, stackoverflow se bugea a veces y omite parte del texto, lo reconoce como código de la página o algo de eso y no lo muestra en el cuadro de la pregunta

Comment: Vale, no he dicho nada, ya se ha aceptado la edición, deberías poder verlo ya

Comment: Ahora sí lo veo. De todos modos, si envía `.send(null)`  el servidor no recibirá nada. Borro comentario anterior. Tienes razón, ese `include` no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: Si, he quitado el include y he dejado pais como pais.html y sigo teniendo el mismo error.Se supone que en esta línea httpObject.open("GET", "leerbd.php?pais=" + pais ,true); ( de pais.html) le paso el pais a leerbd.php. Pero me da el error en la [ 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM provincias where pais =  '".$_GET['pais']."'"; " ] . Habría otra manera de pasarle el pais a leerbd.php?

Comment: he quitado también httpObject.send(null);

Comment: pero lo has cambiado por httpObject.send() ??

Comment: si, lo he dejado por  httpObject.send()

Answer (score 0):

Dani, el problema principal de tu código es que tú estás enviando *nada* al hacer esto:

<s>`httpObject.send(null);`</s><sup>1</sup>

Prueba de esta manera:

```
function Provincias(){
        var pais = document.getElementById('pais').value; //recogemos el pais
        httpObject = getHTTPObject(); 
        if (httpObject != null) {
            httpObject.open("POST", "leerbd.php", true); 
            httpObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpObject.send("pais="+pais);

            httpObject.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(httpObject.readyState == 4  && httpObject.status == 200) 
                /*cuando acabe de cargar leerbd.php /*mostramos el contenido generado en suma.php */
                {

                     document.getElementById('provincias').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD**
>
> El código en `leerbd.php` es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Si
>   te interesa corregir ese error, una vez solucionado el problema
>   original planteado, lo comentas para sugerirte un código corrigiendo
>   ese fallo.

---

<sup>1</sup> Curiosamente, la documentación de MDN en Castellano muestra ejemplos erroneos sobre el método `send`, indicando que a este método se le puede enviar `null`, lo cual no tendría ningún sentido. El código entre la [versión en inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) (correcto)  y la [versión en castellano](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Primeros_Pasos) (incorrecto), es totalmente distinto en cuanto al uso de `send`.

Comment: Los parámetros los pasa en la url de la petición, sí se lo está pasando.

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil el método que envía es `send`. Si a ese método tú le pones  `.send(null)` simplemente estás anulando todo lo anterior. Es como si tú tuvieras una función cualquiera que recibe parámetros, tú construyes los parámetros bien antes de usar la función, pero al final le envías `null`, lo que la función recibirá será `null`, no los parámetros que construiste bien antes de hacer la llamada. Aquí, el servidor recibirá lo que le envíes con `send`.

Comment: Ahhhhmmm, va, de todas formas, el include del principio también está mal puesto, el fallo del `Undefined Index` viene de ahí casi seguro, simplemente porque está intentando cargar el archivo al cargar la página